# "Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The 'integer' plugin does not exist."

Tags: 8, plugins

When I try to update from drupal 8.27 to 8.35, I get the following error. How can I resolve this issue?

> Failed: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "integer" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of C:\Users\ven_arajendra\Sites\devdesktop\offshore2-dev\docroot\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryTrait.php).

Comment: @Smartsheeteng what wiil be the location for /tmp/log in windows enviroment i am using Acquia desktop

Comment: Check you form and view displays for type: integer. That change to something that actually exists, e.g. number_integer.

Comment: @Berdir you are right in some way. when i do a fresh drupal install with out any configuration and contributed module  i am able to upgrade from 8.27-8.35 with out error. but i dont see Integer in my form and display of current site

Comment: @berdir is there a way to list the available form/view display types?

Comment: with php code yes, they are plugins, so you can list the array keys of the field formatter and field widget plugin manager getDefinition() calls

Answer (score 1):

As an option just try to add this code in the enabled custom module in your project.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info_alter().
 */
function custom_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition[] $fields */
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'menu_link_content' && isset($fields['weight'])) {
    $options = $fields["weight"]->getDisplayOptions('view');
    // Lets check if field definition is buggy.
    if ($options['type'] === 'integer') {
      $options['type'] = 'number_integer';
      // @TODO: This should be fixed in the menu_link_content core module.
      // @see https://www.drupal.org/node/2903161
      $fields['weight']->setDisplayOptions('view', $options);
    }
  }
}
```

Or try to use [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/menu_link_content-wrong_field_view_display_option_type-2903161-30-8.5.x.patch) from [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2903161)